# Mounting WLAN router, switch, 2 Raspberry Pis and a power strip

Tags: wiring, wood, screws, mounting, mount

Hardware I would like to mount

- Router: AVM FRITZ!Box 7590
- Switch: Netgear GS116E-200PES 16-Port
- 2 * Raspberry Pis (3 & 4)
- various CAT.7 cables
- Powerstrip
- ??? (ideas are welcome, should be related to router)

The switch may be a bit oversized. It comes from my old apartment where I had a LAN port in every corner in every room. I still would like to continue use it in case I'm moving to a new apartment where it can be put to good use.

I want to mount it on a wood board and place the board on a wall. That wood board can be put and removed from the wall (so no permanent install) in case I'm moving to a new apartment I can just take the wood board with me instead of rewiring everything again.

My questions:

- How thick should the wood be?
- What kind of screws should I buy? (How big and how deep?)
- For the wall mounting:

  - How do I create the "hooks" so I can mount it on the wall and remove it from the wall? Like when you are hanging up pictures. Which "hooks" should I get?
- Cable management:

  - What do I buy for cable management?
- What do I need to pay attention to?

  - Risk of fire due to hardware's close proximity to wood?
  - Bad idea, because ... ? Do this instead?
  - ...

I've seen a nice DIY article about such project before but I lost the article. Answers with links to those articles are also welcome.
I'm a novice at home improvement and would like to start with something small like this.

Answer (score 2):

1/2" plywood would be fine.  If the hardware has keyhole mounting holes, I'd get 1/2" pan head screws for that.  Get whatever size would fit the keyhole.  Disclaimer: YMMV, IMHO there's no fire risk, despite all the hardware, there's very little power actually being drawn, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Command (brand) hooks are usually the go-to for attaching things to walls without damaging the surface, but you are probably above the limit for what they can hold.  A small picture hook would probably do, although would leave a small hole.